# Enable FEDERATED ENGINE error

Tags: mysql, federated

I need to enable FEDERATED ENGINE on Mysql (version 5.5.35).

I set in `/etc/my.cnf` file line `federated`.

Restart my mysql server, then check in mysql using command `SHOW ENGINES`, and result is:

```
FEDERATED   NO  Federated MySQL storage engine  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Also I tried to install plugin federated, but the result is:

```
mysql> install plugin federated soname 'ha_federated.so';
ERROR 1125 (HY000): Function 'federated' already exists
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210309/how-can-i-enable-federated-engine-in-mysql-after-installation). But with no luck. FEDERATED still not supported. What to do?